# How do I share a folder between Ubuntu 22.04 (client) and Windows 7 (guest) using qemu-kvm

Tags: permissions, samba, windows-7, virtualization, shared-folders

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 on a homemade PC: AMD Ryzen, Gigabyte X570 motherboard with a Samsung 980 Pro SSD. I've already created a few shared folders via Samba, but I'm often given the "you don't have access to this file" message for files I create on the Windows 7 guest and drag and drop into the shared folder and then attempt to open in Ubuntu.

I know about `chmod` and `chown`, but I don't know how to use them. Since I don't understand the structure of Ubuntu, I am unable to `cd` around my system to actually run `chmod` and `chown` on the shared folder. The outcome I am looking for is a simple shared folder with files that I completely own. In other words, the "you don't have permission to use this file" error message will never appear when attempting to open a file I created in Windows 7, but now I want it to be opened in Ubuntu (in the shared folder). The *Permissions* tab in Properties (in Ubuntu) for all files in the shared folder will always have my name in it.

Answer (score 0):

> The outcome I am looking for is a simple shared folder with files that
> I completely own. In other words, the "you don't have permission to
> use this file" error message will never appear when attempting to open
> a file I created in Windows 7, but now I want it to be opened in
> Ubuntu (in the shared folder).

The exact same recommendation I gave you in the Ubuntu forum:

So as not to interfere with any other shared folders you may have set I propose setting up a new folder to share and share that one. You can use this as a template to modify your existing share definitions.

**NOTE: Change morbius below to your Ubuntu login user name.**

Create a new "Public2" folder:

```
sudo mkdir -p /srv/Public2
```

Change ownership to you:

```
sudo chown morbius /srv/Public2
```

Edit /etc/samba/smb.conf and at the bottom of the file add a new share definition that looks like this:

```
[Public2]
path = /srv/Public2
read only = no
force user = morbius
guest ok = yes
```

Restart smbd:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

All new files added to this share by the client will have you as owner.